# Angular JS issue with string.length in templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with AngularJS (version 1.2.6).

For some reason that I could not understand I cannot access the `length` property of a string variable stored in the `$scope`.

In the template:

```
String '{{myObject.someVariable}}' has length '{{myObject.someVariable.length}}'.
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.myObject = {} ; 

//asynchronuous loading of myObject 
SomeService.loadObject(function(result)){
    $scope.myObject = result ; 
    console.log("Content: '%s', length:'%i'",$scope.myObject.someVariable,$scope.myObject.someVariable.length);
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

The result is :

```
String 'aaaa' has length ''.
```

In the console I correctly see `Content:'aaaa', length:'4'`

This is ennoying because I display (or not) some parts of the template depending on the string size.

*Update*

`$scope.myObject.someVariable` is a string. I added a breakpoint in the callback function with two watches :

- `$scope.myObject.someVariable` : "aaaa"
- `typeof($scope.myObject.someVariable)` : "string"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is `someVariable` a string? If not, you might have to cast it to a string before accessing the length property. Any easy way is to concatenate it with an empty string:

```
{{(myObject.someVariable + '').length}}
```

Comment: `someVariable` is a string (see update). Altough it is not very elegant, `{{(myObject.someVariable + '').length}}` works fine. Seems like a bug in AngularJS. Thanks :-)

Comment: i seem to have the same problem, but this doesnt solve my problem. I can bind to `myObject.someVariable` but `(myObject.someVariable + '').length` doesnt work either in `{{}}` nor like that `ng-if="(myObject.someVariable + '').length > 0"`

Answer (score 0):

You could work around this problem  by setting up a manual watcher in the scope, to update a variable with the length of the string:

```
$scope.$watch('myObject.someVariable',function(newValue) {
  $scope.myVariableLength = newValue.length; 
})
```

Comment: I prefer the other solution which does not pollute `$scope` with extra variables, but thanks for the idea.